# iReport designer unable to create chart theme

Tags: ireport

I'm using *iReport* designer for designing charts.  I'm unable to create custom chart theme, I am getting unexpected error during jar creation.

[image: Unexpected error occured during jar creation while creating custom chart themes in ireport designer]

Please help me.